# Groovy: When I debuging object is not null

Tags: debugging, groovy, nullpointerexception

I have some problem with groovy. Sometimes when script is executed then exception NullPointerException is thrown but allways when I debugging the script the exception is no occurred. It looks like that my object sometimes is not created in time and Groovy try execute method on it. Someone have idea what could be the reason of problem:
Below is mentioned exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getService() on null object.
```

Comment: Error message is clearly says the the reason. Other, would you edit the question and add your script?

Comment: If you add the code it may give some relevant details of the reasons to that error.